# how to append multiple users input to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to append multiple user's input to a dictionary and then print all of them but whenever I run the code, I get only the last input in the console. Can anyone help me with this as I am new to coding from non tech background

```
from album import make_album

while True:
    aName = input("Enter ur fav artist name? \n")
    fsong = input("Enter ur fav artist's song: \n")
    num = input("Enter total song by ur fav artist: \n")
    print("press 'yes' tfor another poll or press 'quit' anytime to exit:")
    anotherPoll = input()
    if anotherPoll == "quit":
        break
    
make_album(aName, fsong, num)
```

Comment: If `make_album` is the function that updates the dictionary, then you should move it inside the `while loop`.

Comment: I see you ask your user for input, but there is no dictionary and there is no print. What do the other parts of your code do?

Comment: Insufficient data. Your sample code does not define, let alone use, a dictionary. I suspect the relevant code is in the `make_album` implementation that you didn't show us. Downvoting your question because it looks like you made zero effort to solve the problem on your own. That is, you did not show us what you tried, or even describe what you tried. Which suggests you are asking the community to provide a solution for free.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use dictionary like this:

```
count_in = 1
dict_in = {}
while True:
    aName = input("Enter ur fav artist name? \n")
    fsong = input("Enter ur fav artist's song: \n")
    num = input("Enter total song by ur fav artist: \n")
    dict_in[count_in] = {"aName"+str(count_in) : aName , "fsong"+str(count_in): fsong, "num"+str(count_in) : num}
    print("press 'yes' tfor another poll or press 'quit' anytime to exit:")
    count_in += 1
    anotherPoll = input()
    if anotherPoll == "quit":
        break
```

output:

```
Enter ur fav artist name? 
a
Enter ur fav artist's song: 
a
Enter total song by ur fav artist: 
2
press 'yes' tfor another poll or press 'quit' anytime to exit:
yes
Enter ur fav artist name? 
b
Enter ur fav artist's song: 
b
Enter total song by ur fav artist: 
3
press 'yes' tfor another poll or press 'quit' anytime to exit:
quit
{1: {'aName1': 'a', 'fsong1': 'a', 'num1': '2'},
 2: {'aName2': 'b', 'fsong2': 'b', 'num2': '3'}}
```